# How to uninstall framaroot

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, uninstallation, unrooting

i search in google and i can't find some easy way to uninstall the application (it can't be found in the play store apps). How i can uninstall (or delete) framaroot?

Thanks

Update:

I suscefully uninstalled the in the settings of the smarthphone, but it's still have root permission the android.

The questions is: how to take away the root permission?

Comment: Well i found this to delete (uninstall) SuperUser:

Use root explorer and delete superuser.apk from the /system/app folder(1). Go to the Android market and download and install super user. Use root explorer again and delete su from /system/bin (2). Go to the market and uninstall super user.

 (1) I use Root App Delete, but the idea is the same.
 (2) I try to delete but it's unsuccessful :)

Comment: You probably should try a reboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found this to delete (uninstall) SuperUser:

- Use root explorer and delete superuser.apk from the /system/app folder(1).
- Go to the Android market and download and install super user. Use root explorer again and delete su from /system/bin (2).
- Go to the market and uninstall super user.

Notes:

(1) I use Root App Delete, but the idea is the same.

(2) I try to delete but it's unsuccessful :)

I solve finally using this guide:

http://www.androidrootz.com/2012/08/how-to-unroot-any-android-device.html

Resume:

- Install es file explorer,
- Install supersu
- Start SuperSu
- in es file explorer start root explorer
- delete /system/bin/su
- delete /system/xbin/su
- Uninstall supersu

Answer (score -1):

Run framaroot.apk and choose unroot.